# How to change size and position of image in java applet

Tags: java, applet

I am making a java applet that have several rectangles of varying sizes that change position and size throughout the program. Is there a way to instead have a rectangular image that changes size and position just like these rectangles?

Comment: What applet kit are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The question depends.  Do you want to scale the image and maintain it's aspect ratio or not.

If you do, then you also need to decide if you want the image to fill the available area (possibly overfilling) or fit within.

For more details, check out [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)

The easiest solution would be to use [`Image#getScaledInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29) and simply paint the image using [`Graphics#drawImage(Image, int, int, ImageObserver)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29)

But you should beware of the issues with this method.  See [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)